# Dropdown menu with Bootstrap 4 only drops once in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, yarnpkg

I recently updated to Bootstrap 4.0.0, I'm running Rails 5.1.5 and I installed BS as specified in the README in their github.

Furthermore it's been added to package.json for yarn.

In gemfile : gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0' gem 'jquery-rails'

In package.json : "bootstrap": "^4.0.0", "popper.js": "^1.12.9", "jquery": "^3.3.0"

I set it in my application.scss : @import "bootstrap";

My app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Now I trying a basic exemple from an online doc :

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="about-us" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        About Us
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Story</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Team</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I click the button, the menu appears, but if I click again it doesn't goes back, and after that I can't click it anymore, it's like frozen.

Comment: I have tried it on `https://codepen.io`, it seems everything is working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added

```
$(document).ready(function() { $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown(); })
```

in a random js file, and it works fine at the first click

Answer (score 2):

Try just to include bootstrap script files directly in your HTML file, it should do the thing and I think it shouldn't be a problem for you.

You can get them here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/
It should like this:

```
<!--Bootstrap CSS should be in head tag-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--Your dropdown-->
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="about-us" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        About Us
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Story</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Team</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Bootstrap script files, they come at the end of your body tag-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here is a working JSFiddle with those files: https://jsfiddle.net/c5bnsrsy/1/

Comment: It works when I add the jquery and bootstrap script tag at the end of my applicatoin.html. In fact it almost works, first cliick is innefective, but after that it's the expected behaviour.
But the bigger problem is that I'm not supposed to be doing that, I got bundler and yarn to assist the package management, they are supposed to be doing their jobs, why isn't it working ?

Comment: I don't have any experience with rails but I found this: $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
});
If you put it to your js file it should be working
OR
add to your gem file: *gem 'bootstrap-sass'* then run: *bundle install* and then it should work

Comment: I deleted all scripts references in my application.html and just added $(document).ready(function() { $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown(); }) in a random js file, and it works fine at the first click. It's much more graceful, but still, I think it should be manage by bootstrap or jquery. 

What is strange is that I'm abble to use $() from jquery and I'm using  classes from Bootstrap 4, so they are here, but not fully here, that is so strange
Bootstap sass is using Bootstrap 3 only, so I deleted it from my project, I read somewhere that BS4 is from start built with sass, so I'v got that instead