# Bootstrap Navbar dropdown not working Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

Whenever I click on it it just redirects me by adding a '/#' to the end of my route.  There are not jquery errors in the console log when I click the drop down.  Here's my applicaiton.js:

```
//
//= jquery
//= jquery-ui
//= popper
//= bootstrap-sprockets
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree
```

I have the JQuery-Rails gem along with jquery-ui-rails.  The console log shows now errors with jquery/javascript when I click on the dropdown either.  Here's my server logs:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-25 14:06:27 -0500
Processing by StaticController#homepage as HTML
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/sohel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Rendering static/homepage.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered static/homepage.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_nav.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 47ms (Views: 41.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Here's the view erb file for the navbar component.  It was basically taken directly off the bootstrap website:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light custom-nav">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <%= link_to 'Home', root_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <%= link_to 'Time Entries', posts_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors in the console, especially ones when you click the dropdown?

Comment: I am not getting any errors in the console

Answer (score 2):

Setting an explicit href (`"#"`) will make your browser change the url fragment, you can remove it (`<a href class="..." ...>`) and the browser wont try to follow it.

```
<a
  class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
  href 
  id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" 
  data-toggle="dropdown" 
  aria-haspopup="true" 
  aria-expanded="false"
>
  Dropdown link
</a>
```

On the other side, the drop down should toggle. Check the network inspector and ensure you are actually loading the application JavaScript at all.

## UPDATE

There is an error in your `application.js` file. The libraries are just named and not `require`d. It should read:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

(also notice the dot at the end of `require_tree` line)

Comment: Getting rid of the a class entirely removes the dropdown link entirely, is there a workaround to this?  It is loading the application.js in the inspector on page load, and when clicking the dropdown, turbolinks and javascript but are running in the inspector.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182263/dropdown-menu-with-bootstrap-4-only-drops-once-in-rails)

Had to add the following script tags under my closing body tag, in my application.html.erb layout file:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Check updated answer, you were not loading jquery/popper/bootstrap javascripts correctly.