# Rails 6 Bootstrap Dropdown Navbar not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap with a Rails 6 application. I have used yarn to install `jquery` and `popper.js`. I have included a dropdown in my navbar, but it does not open. It just redirects me to the current link + `#`, which doesn't do anything.

My header ERB:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

My `application.js`:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap")
```

My `environment.js`:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
    })
)

module.exports = environment
```

And in my SCSS:

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I believe I am following everything I need to use Webpacker with Rails and Bootstrap. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first answer to this below Stackoverflow question works for me. It is not the proper solution, but You can try to catch up with the working dropdown.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49182263/dropdown-menu-with-bootstrap-4-only-drops-once-in-rails

Tested the mentioned solution with this versions in Gemfile

```
ruby '3.1.2'

gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.3', '>= 7.0.3.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'popper_js', '~> 1.14.3'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.2.1'
```

Comment: That still doesn't work. And I would like to use the proper solution if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

to my `application.html.erb`, but I don't think this is the proper solution, so any other solution would be appreciated